# First child element JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

so I have this json file where I want to get the first child element but don't know how.

```
$.ajax({
    url: link,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.results == null) {
            return;
        }
        deck = data.results.deck;
        publishers = data.results.publishers[0].publisher
    }
//...
```

it works to get the deck value but not to get the `<publisher>` in `<publishers>`

json file 
http://www.giantbomb.com/api/game/3030-2/?api_key=9f4a7e5504989d2c50606e01a6b8c1b25a6953fa&format=jsonp&format=jsonp&&json_callback=%3F

Comment: If it's XML, why are you expecting it to be JSONP ?

Comment: If you're using jQuery (which it appears you are), you could pass the the data string into the main function, ie $(data), then use jQuery to get whatever children you want, eg $(data).children("publishers").children(":first").
EDIT
Since this data is in JSON and not XML, my solution won't work. Could you post the actual JSON string so we can get a better idea as to what we're dealing with?

Comment: It loads a json file, I just added an xml file so you'd see the structure

Comment: So you have JSON, but you decided to show us XML so we would understand what the JSON looks like. What a genius!

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I've added json file in post. Or here http://www.giantbomb.com/api/game/3030-2/?api_key=9f4a7e5504989d2c50606e01a6b8c1b25a6953fa&format=jsonp&format=jsonp&&json_callback=?

Comment: It should be this, http://www.giantbomb.com/api/game/3030-2/?api_key=9f4a7e5504989d2c50606e01a6b8c1b25a6953fa&format=jsonp&format=jsonp&&json_callback=?

Comment: Okay, so first of, results is an array, so you should have to provide an index to access anything from it (not sure why data.results.deck works). Second, it's empty, so we can't help you with the rest of the problem. EDIT it's empty for me because no JSON callback was provided. Could you just add an example result to your question?

Comment: "publishers":[{"api_detail_url":"http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/api\/publisher\/3010-7\/","id":7,"name":"Software Storm, Inc.","site_detail_url":"http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/software-storm-inc\/3010-7\/"}],

Comment: data.results.publishers[0] returns an the first publisher. You get an error because publishers[0] has no publisher object, therefore data.results.publishers[0].publisher is undefined. So data.results.publishers[0] is all you need.